# Subtract value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table,as per requirement we need to subtract the values as given below. kindly assist me how to solve this puzzle....

```
Table1
MONTH   Fee(Advance) 
APRIL   5000 


Table2  
MONTH   Fee 
MAY     2000 
JUNE    300 
JULY    1800 
AUG     1200 
Sep     1500 



Expecting Result 
ROW 1   MAY     5000(TABLE1.ADVANCE)-2000(TABLE2.FEE)=   3000
ROW 2   JUNE    3000-300                             =   2700
ROW 3   JULY    2700-1800                            =   900
ROW 4   AUG     900-1200                             =   -300
ROW 5   Sep     -300-1500                            =   -1800
```

Comment: It looks like you need to do a `JOIN` between those tables using MONTH as your join condition and then subtract the other columns. From your data is not very clear what are you expecting and how can you get there. Please clarify.

Comment: How is the DBMS to know what 'AUG' means? Do you have a table listing all month names you are using along with their month number?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that table1 contains one record only? If not, what to do when there is, say, an additional record for JUNE|1000?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right way of doing this. Instead of SQL statement, maybe stored procedure will help?

```
DECLARE @AdvanceFee INT;
DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
DECLARE @cnt_total INT = (Select Count(MONTH) From Table2);

SET @AdvanceFee = (Select Fee(Advance) from Table1)

WHILE @cnt <= @cnt_total 
BEGIN 

    Select MONTH, @AdvanceFee = @AdvanceFee - Fee 
    FROM Table2
    WHERE ROW_NUMBER = @cnt

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a table containing month names and numbers ('MAY' = 5, 'Sep' = 9, ...). Then use `SUM OVER` to get a running total:

```
select
  t.month,
  (select fee from table1 where month = 'APRIL') - sum(t.fee) over (order by m.monthnum)
    as balance
from table2 t
join months m on m.name = t.month
order by m.monthnum;
```